# After upgrade to 22.04 cifs uses uid and gid from remote device instead the specified a mount

Tags: permissions, mount, cifs

For many years I have mounted my Synology NAS via cifs with the uid and gid options in `/etc/fstab`, so Ubuntu presented the file tree as owned by this user/group and the NAS wrote the files as written by the user specified in the mount. This worked fine.

Now I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and it seems to have taken the approch to read and respect the permissions in the filesystem on the NAS. The issue is it uses the nummeric IDs, so on my Ubuntu my user is 1000 but on the NAS it is 1026 and thus Ubuntu gives me a permission denied although the NAS is just fine with me reading or writing files (when I uses sudo on Ubuntu).

How can I get cifs to just accept the uid and gid I specify and just ignore what permission the NAS tells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug in Ubuntu 22.04. You can either downgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, or mount the NAS with the "nounix" option.

Comment: I used the nounix option to get running again. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, but using this fixed it.

//machine/documents /mnt/machine/documents cifs vers=1.0,forceuid,forcegid,mfsymlinks,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,rw,_netdev,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).